# external dataset learning in python for machine learning

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, dataset, naivebayes

Hi I want classify a dataset using naivebayesclassifier.For that I want to use external dataset which i have downloaded from google.this dataset contains a two folder for positive reviews and negative reviews.Each folder contains 1000 .txt files.How to import this file in my code as a train dataset in python.I am new to machine learning so I have very less idea about that.Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.listdir`, from (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html), e.g.:

```
import os
fileList = os.listdir('train_directory')
for file in fileList:
    # add content of file to dataset.
```

Comment: os.listdir code works.thanks for guiding.I want to read every .txt file and extract all positive words and tag the words as positive at the end.Below code but it is showing error stating 0_9.txt this file name does not exist but its there in the folder                                  posfilenames =           os.listdir("C:/Users/Sharmili/Desktop/movie_reviews/pos")
    print(posfilenames)for filename in posfilenames:
    f = open(filename,'r')
    reviews = f.read()
    pos_reviews = reviews.split()
    pos_reviews.append((create_word_feature(words),"positive"))
print(len(pos_reviews))

Comment: can you please help me out

Comment: you need to use f = open(dir + "/" + filename)

Comment: I have tried your code but it was not working so I tried the following code for filename in posfilenames:
    f = open(os.path.join("C:/Users/Sharmili/Desktop/movie_reviews/pos",filename),'r')                                                                                                  pos_reviews = f.read().split(" ")
    print(pos_reviews)

Comment: Although it is printing the words but it is giving error                                return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 803: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right encoding. Maybe those txt files are not really text files but binary encodes. Then you would have to use open(file, 'rb'). This is hard to answer without knowing the content of the text files. But i can assure you I use the code above regularly for my files and it works. Anyways you can try to open one file to see what the difference is between my code and the code that works for you.